# Nome na classe de acordo com o input

Tags: python

```
class Conta:

   def __init__(self, numero, titular, saldo, limite):
       print("Construindo objeto ... {}".format(self))
       self.__numero = numero
       self.__titular = titular
       self.__saldo = saldo
       self.__limite = limite

  

numero_conta = input("Numero da conta:")
nome_titular = input("Nome do titular:")
saldo_conta  = input("Saldo da conta:")
limite_conta = input("Limite da conta:")
NOME_AQUI = Conta(numero_conta,nome_titular,saldo_conta,limite_conta)
```

Pessoal, sou iniciante e em python e estou com uma duvida que talvez possa ser muito boba, tenho esse codigo ai que cria uma classe, gostaria que onde está NOME_AQUI, fosse na verdade o nome passado do input, exemplo, input("Guilherme"), no código ficaria Guilherme = Conta(......)
Como posso fazer para receber esse string daquele jeito?

Comment: Não sei se é muito pertinente fazer isso...

Comment: Não seria melhor manter um dicionário cujo as chaves sejam os nomes dos titulares e os valores as referências as respectivas contas.

Comment: Um dicionário, além de mais simples, também resolve casos em que haja caracteres inválidos em identificadores, como por exemplo espaços. Por exemplo, se o nome digitado for "Fulano de tal", não é possível ter uma variável com esse nome (por causa dos espaços), mas em um dicionário é perfeitamente possível uma chave ter os espaços. Esta é a limitação da resposta abaixo inclusive (além de ser uma complicação desnecessária, já que um dicionário seria muito mais simples)

Answer (score -3):

Se o nome que será definido para `NOME_AQUI` seria um novo `input`, além dos que você adicionou. Você pode tentar criar uma outra classe para representar todo grupo que irá receber os dados da classe `Conta`,
por exemplo:

```
class Conta:
   def __init__(self, numero, titular, saldo, limite):
       print("Construindo objeto ... {}".format(self))
       self.numero = numero
       self.titular = titular
       self.saldo = saldo
       self.limite = limite

class Entidade:
    def get_entidade(self):
        NOME_AQUI = input("Nome: ")
        numero_conta = input("Numero da conta:")
        nome_titular = input("Nome do titular:")
        saldo_conta  = input("Saldo da conta:")
        limite_conta = input("Limite da conta:")
        nova_entidade = {NOME_AQUI: Conta(numero_conta,
                        nome_titular,saldo_conta,limite_conta)}
        self.__dict__.update(nova_entidade)

e = Entidade()
e.get_entidade()
...
print(e.Guilherme.titular) # caso tenha preenchido em NOME_AQUI com 'Guilherme'
```

No metodo `get_entidade()` você irá criar um novo atributo no objeto com os parametros atribuidos. Considerando que você respondeu com o nome `Guilherme` para o `input` de `NOME_AQUI`, terá dessa forma o novo atributo criado no objeto `e` (`e.Guilherme`), que será uma instância da classe `Conta`.

---

Uma segunda maneira, seria adicionar a sua variavel ao namespace do ambiente usando a função [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), uma [referência](https://www.phylos.net/2021-06-01/python-escopos-e-namespaces/):

```
class Conta:
   def __init__(self, numero, titular, saldo, limite):
       print("Construindo objeto ... {}".format(self))
       self.numero = numero
       self.titular = titular
       self.saldo = saldo
       self.limite = limite


def my_input(text):
    nome_entidade = input(text)
    if not nome_entidade[0].isalpha():
        raise Exception("Nomes de variaveis não podem começar com numeros.")
    return nome_entidade 

def atualiza_namespace():
    numero_conta = input("Numero da conta:")
    nome_titular = input("Nome do titular:")
    saldo_conta  = input("Saldo da conta:")
    limite_conta = input("Limite da conta:")
    NOME_AQUI = my_input("Nome da variavel: ")
    globals()[NOME_AQUI] = Conta(numero_conta, nome_titular,
                    saldo_conta,limite_conta)
    return NOME_AQUI

nome_entidade = atualiza_namespace()
print(Guilherme.titular) # caso tenha preenchido em NOME_AQUI com 'Guilherme'
print(globals()[nome_entidade].limite) # também pode acessar a variavel a partir do dicionario do namespace.
```

Depois de chamar a função `atualiza_namespace()` e preencher todos os campos, caso tenha preenchido o `my_input("Nome da variavel: ")` com o nome `Guilherme`, terá a nova variavel adicionada ao namespace do modulo, que da mesma forma, será uma instância da classe `Conta`.

OBS: Esses são apenas alguns exemplos, coloquei apenas uma minima verificação na função `my_input()`.